# Firebase .info/connected showing wrong connection states

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using the presence system in Firebase to show "Online", if my client is connected to the network and "Offline", if the connection gets lost somehow.

This is very important for my client as it indicates, if the user can send a message now.

**It works well sometimes and sometimes not** and there lies the problem.

This is what I am doing,

```
mConnectionRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected");
        mConnectionRef.addValueEventListener(mPresenceListener);
```

and this,

```
private ValueEventListener mPresenceListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
            Timber.d("Connected: %s", connected);
            Presence.getInstance().setIsOnline(connected);
            if (connected) {
                if (mPresenceStatus != null) {
                    mPresenceStatus.setText(ResourceUtils.getString(R.string.label_online));
                    Drawable image = ResourceUtils.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_presence_online);
                    mPresenceStatus.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(image, null, null, null);
                }
            } else {
                mPresenceStatus.setText(ResourceUtils.getString(R.string.label_offline));
                Drawable image = ResourceUtils.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_presence_offline);
                mPresenceStatus.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(image, null, null, null);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            Presence.getInstance().setIsOnline(false);
            mPresenceStatus.setText(ResourceUtils.getString(R.string.label_offline));
            Drawable image = ResourceUtils.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_presence_offline);
            mPresenceStatus.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(image, null, null, null);
        }
    };
```

Sometimes, after the client is idle for a long period of time and then I open the app, I can see that it prints "Connected: true" and then immediately prints "Connected: false" and this repeats every 2-3 seconds even if the client has a working network connection.

Now the solution to this problem is to log out using mFirebaseUser.logout() and log in again and then the listener works perfectly.

Now if I don't use the app again for a few hours this problem occurs again and the listener starts behaving abnormally.

What am I doing wrong here? What the problem actually is? How can this weird problem be solved?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This could be due to a failure to refresh the auth token.  Can you make sure you're using at least version 9.6 of firebase-database (in your gradle file)?  There was a fix that may address this.

Comment: @MichaelLehenbauer I am using version 9.6.1. This seems to be a major problem for me because of which I am unable to push my app to production. Can you help me with any other fix?

Comment: Can you enable logging (FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.Debug)) and email me (michael@firebase.com) with the output when it's in the broken state?

Comment: @MichaelLehenbauer i'm having a problem that seems related. I've created a different issue as it was a bit long for a comment, and not appropriate as an answer to this topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40971536/firebase-android-being-very-long-to-reconnect links to the logs are available there. Thanks!