# Firebase Android taking up to 45min to reconnect

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

On some devices (list given below), Firebase consistently takes between 20 and 45 minutes to reconnect after the internet connection is regained. Can anything be done to speed things up ?

I first thought the problem came from the `.info/connected` event listener not being triggered, but then I realized that if there were some pending writes, they also got committed after this long delay, when the event listener was triggered.

I tried listening for the connectivity state and manually call `goOffline` / `goOnline`, but it didn't yield any results.

The problem can be reproduced with the android getting started database example, for example by adding the following to the `onCreate` method of the `SignInActivity`.

```
// test data value event listener
mDatabase.child("test").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        String value = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
        Log.d(TAG, value);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());
    }
});
// test presence value event listener
mDatabase.child(".info/connected").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(connected));
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());
    }
});
```

In case it helps, using the web firebase package and react-native displays the same behavior on the same devices.

Here is a list of devices where I've seen the problem:

- samsung galaxy view
- chuwi-hi12 - 5.1
- touchlet x13 octa
- asus zenpad 300 c
- huawei mediapad t2

Those devices never display this behavior:

- acer iconia one 10 b3-a30-k5es
- samsung galaxy tab E - 5.1
- archos 121D neon

Finally, here are the logs for a device without a problem and a device with the problem:

- log ok: https://gist.github.com/VonD/eb79a57e69bc5026f0a1f145635ccd6a
- log not ok : https://gist.github.com/VonD/a26e194859453e2c538dd8b9e6573b62

In both cases, i just started the app, turned wifi off, waited for the `.info/connected` event listener to be triggered, and turned wifi back on. Timestamps show the differences in delay on both devices.

Comment: Did you found a fix yet? I have this problem too. On my side it takes 3 minutes to reconnect to Firebase.

Comment: @Displee Unfortunately not :( We had extensive conversations with Firebase support about this, and even ended up shipping to them a device showing this behaviour! Nothing conclusive came out of it. You could maybe reach out to them and share all the info you have hoping they might discover the issue.

Comment: Damn, I contacted Firebase and they told me that this is a device related problem. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55278817/firebase-takes-3-minutes-to-reconnect-on-android-4-4-4