# Firebase takes ~3 minutes to reconnect on Android 4.4.4

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

The Firebase service on a Samsung SM-T560 with Android 4.4.4 takes ~3 minutes to re-connect (after I disabled wifi and enabled it again). This problem doesn't occur when the same app is being ran on a HUAWEI MediaPad T3 10 (AGS-W09) with Android 7.0.

I'm currently using the following Firebase version:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:17.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0'
```

I've registered 2 services in my manifest file:

```
<service android:name=".firebase.FirebaseInstanceIdService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<service
    android:name=".firebase.FirebaseMessagingService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Edit:
I've also tried to use a lower Firebase version:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0'
```

Sadly this didn't do the trick.

Does anyone have an idea why Firebase takes so long to reconnect? In Android 7.0 it directly reconnects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've received a message from Google with the following:

> Hello,
>
> This appears to be more of a device problem than a Firebase issue. The
>   network is handled by the device, so when any Firebase service can
>   connect would also be dependent on that.
>
> If you have Firebase specific questions, feel free to reach out again.
>
> Regards, Andy

Looks like I've to contact Samsung.

Edit:

I've contacted Samsung. They told me to reset the tablet.

I've performed a hard-reset and this problem doesn't occur anymore. Thank god.

This guide worked for my tablet: https://support.bell.ca/mobility/smartphones_and_mobile_internet/samsung-galaxy-tab-e.how_to_perform_a_hard_reset_when_my_samsung