# Firebase Database connection gets connected and disconnected repeatedly(every second)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

- Firebase Database connection gets connected and disconnected in every second repeatedly till the app is not closed.Due to this fluctuation:

  1. FirebaseDatabase is unable to save and receive data from firebase server.
  2. ValueEventListener are not invoking.
- Code has been tested in below devices and in both devices problem has occured :-

  1. Emulator

     Google Play Services 10.0.84
     Android version 6.0
     `dependencies{
     compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
     compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
     }`
  2. Samsung Galaxy J2
     Google Play Services 10.2.97
     Android version 5.1.1
     `dependencies{
     compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
     compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
     }`
- Steps to reproduce problem :

  1. Set the device clock time to current time.
  2. Execute  TestActivity.java 
     When this Activity executes 1st time User will be signed in anonymously with FirebaseAuth,wait few seconds user will be signed in successfully.Now move to 3rd step.
  3. Close the app with back press.
  4. Now increase the device clock time by 2 or more days.
  5. Open the app again and check the logcat. Problem will occur immediately or after few minutes or sometimes even after 1 or 2 hours. If problem has not occurred immediately, then close the app and open it after few minutes or few hours(When device is idle for a 2-3 hours then definitely problem occurs);
- stackoverflow link,which I think relates to this problem is
  [Firebase .info/connected showing wrong connection states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40233039/firebase-info-connected-showing-wrong-connection-states)
- Code which is producing problem is

  ```
  package com.app.sample;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.os.Handler;
  import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
  import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.util.Log;
  import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
  import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
  import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
  import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
  import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
  import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
  import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
  import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
  import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
  import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

  public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
      private final String TAG = "TestActivity";
      Handler handler = new Handler();
      private ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
              boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
              log(connected ? "Online" : "Offline");
          }

          @Override
          public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
              log(databaseError.getDetails());
          }
      };
      private DatabaseReference connectedRef;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
          FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
          if (user == null) {
              signIn();
          } else {
              log("User is already logged in");
          }
          connectedRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected");
          connectedRef.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
      }

      private void signIn() {
          FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInAnonymously()
                  .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                      @Override
                      public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                          if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                              FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                              log("Signed in successfully User id " + user.getUid());
                          } else {
                              log("Unable to authenticate app." + task.getException());
                          }
                      }
                  });
      }

      @Override
      protected void onResume() {
          super.onResume();
          FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOnline();
      }

      @Override
      protected void onStop() {
          super.onStop();
          FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOffline();
      }

      private void log(String msg) {
          Log.e(TAG, msg);
      }

      @Override
      protected void onDestroy() {
          super.onDestroy();
          if (connectedRef != null) {
              connectedRef.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- In logcat below logs are repeated till the app is open.

```
02-07 09:19:16.677 2435-2635/com.google.android.gms I/AuthChimeraService: Executing send connection operation
02-07 09:19:18.185 4633-4660/com.fire.base.test D/EventRaiser: Raising 1 event(s)
02-07 09:19:18.186 4633-4633/com.fire.base.test D/EventRaiser: Raising /.info/connected: VALUE: true
02-07 09:19:18.186 4633-4633/com.fire.base.test E/TestActivity: Online
02-07 09:19:18.588 4633-4660/com.fire.base.test D/EventRaiser: Raising 1 event(s)
02-07 09:19:18.588 4633-4633/com.fire.base.test D/EventRaiser: Raising /.info/connected: VALUE: false
02-07 09:19:18.588 4633-4633/com.fire.base.test E/TestActivity: Offline
02-07 09:19:19.686 2435-2691/com.google.android.gms E/AsyncOperation: serviceID=16, operation=ValidateAuthServiceOperation
    java.lang.NullPointerException: onPostInitComplete can be called only once per call to getRemoteService
          at kpd.a(:com.google.android.gms:74)
          at kme.a(:com.google.android.gms:987)
          at kna.a(:com.google.android.gms:66)
          at kvb.a(:com.google.android.gms:284)
          at ekn.a(:com.google.android.gms:125)
          at ekn.a(:com.google.android.gms:113)
          at kvi.run(:com.google.android.gms:113)
          at kyl.run(:com.google.android.gms:450)
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
          at lco.run(:com.google.android.gms:17)
          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Does your app require that the user change the time on the device like this?  Normally, people (and programs) expect time to move forward predictably.  Otherwise, you'll mess up the way they work (both the people and the programs).

Comment: @Doug Stevenson,No I don't want my user to change device time.
In app I am doing below things:
(1) Using FirebaseAuth to sign in anonymously.
(2)Using Firebase Database to save and fetch data and display it to user.
I am came up with this issue,when my users starts complaining about the app that"After few days app is not working."
Due to this problem:
(1)User leaves bad rating.
(2)User uninstalls the app.
This problem occurs even if device time has not been changed.But it can occur on the same day of install or after few days.

Comment: Currently there is one solution to this problem:
(1)If user is signed out from FirebaseAuth and signed in again.Then problem is solved.
But this solution cannot be implemented in production app.As I cannot ask user again and again to sign out and sign in.
There is some real issue which needs to be investigated and resolved as soon as possible.

Comment: @VIJAYSACHAN I noticed this issue too in my app, were you able to resolve it?

Comment: @ 0x01Brain Sorry for late response.No I am not unable to resolve the issue.This problem usually occurs when user's device clock time is not set to current time.